# In UV is there a way to scale them automatically, like unwrap does but without changing UVs?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, edit-mode, scale

In UVs is there a way to scale them automatically (relative to the 3d model), like unwrap does but without modifying the UVs?

Comment: Hello :). There probably is. Could you please add more details about what you want to achieve?